# Struggling to draw a line across a series of divs

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/B8JYN/1/

```
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#outerdiv {
    height: 50%;
    width: 99%;
        left:1%;
    background-color: #000000;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
}       
#fretboard {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    top:5%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: red;
}

.stringTitle {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #000000;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    width:1%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.string{
    height:16.666%
}

.fret{
    width:8%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}

.fretEnd{
    width:.3%;
    background-color:#e7ebea;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
.E1{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 11%;
}
.B{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 23.5%;
}
.G{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 23.5%;
}
.D{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 23.5%;
}
.A{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 23.5%;
}
.E2{
    background-color:green;
     height: 3%;
    margin-top: 23.5%;
}
</style>
<div class="stringTitle">
          <div class="string">E</div>
          <div class="string">B</div>
          <div class="string">G</div>
          <div class="string">D</div>
          <div class="string">A</div>
          <div class="string">E</div>
</div>
<div id="outerdiv">

    <div id="fretboard">
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fret">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fretEnd">
              <div class="E1"></div>
              <div class="B"></div>
              <div class="G"></div>
              <div class="D"></div>
              <div class="A"></div>
              <div class="E2"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the green lines to be spaced equally in the vertical direction and continuously across from left to right. Hope that makes sense? I'm trying to make this using only percentages rather than specifying px

Comment: You might want to use a charting library to accomplish this. Chart.js, raphael.js and highcharts.js all look like good candidates to accomplish fret-board like line charts.

Comment: I want to stay clear of anything like that. It should be possible with just CSS/HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage based `margin-top` value is relative to the width, therefore the positioning won't be consistent if the width of the browser is changed.

> [**8 Box model - 8.3 Margin properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

One solution would be to absolutely position the elements and use a percentage based `top` value. It's important to relatively position the parent element in order for them to be positioned absolutely relative to the parent, in this case, `.fret`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgtM8/)

```
.E1, .B, .G, .D, .A, .E2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    height: 3%;
}
.E1 {
    top:9.6%;
}
.B {
    top:26.2%;
}
.G {
    top:42.9%;
}
.D {
    top:59.6%;
}
.A {
    top:76.4%;
}
.E2 {
    top:91.2%;
}
```

Those are just rough estimates. You can of course change the values depending on your needs.

Comment: Perfect! I never knew there was a relation between width and height with margins. Cheers

Comment: I don't suppose you would know how to display some text on each fret? like so 
|--A--|--B--|

Comment: @totalitarian I'd suggest using either the `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements. The content value would just be the text.

Comment: Will I need to position it somehow?

Comment: looking at the updated example, the strings extend beyond the end of the body to the right. Testing in firefox only.

Comment: @totalitarian Simply add `overflow:hidden` to `#outerdiv`.. http://jsfiddle.net/nnHfD/

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Why would I not un-accept the answer if the solution had errors? No offence meant, I just thought that was the correct thing to do?